ReadSample not (or very slowly) returning on some Windows 11 systems
We have an application that uses IMFSourceReader::ReadSample to get specific frames out of videos. This has worked reliably for years on Windows 7, 8 and 10.
Now, on Windows 11 it happens on some systems (not all Windows 11 systems are affected by this), that ReadSample either takes around 30 seconds to return (if that is the case, the returned frame is correct), or does not return at all. This makes our application unusable on those Windows 11 installations.
The videos that are affected can be played normally in the windows media player, and also work in a System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement control that is embedded in our application, so I don't think that it's a codec issue.
Has anyone else seen this effect? Or does anyone have an idea on how to debug this? I now have a system available, where I can reproduce this (before, it was just customer reports). I tried using mftrace, but it exits with an exception whenever I try to attach it to our application.

It's not because it used to run that it's not exempt of bugs lying in the dark, unexposed by some Windows setup. Is it the same if you completely disconnect from the network/internet, say. Is memory usage stable? What about all 3rd party apps/codecs?

The problem remains, if the PC is disconnected from the network. Memory usage is stable, and the CPU is not used at all while ReadSample is stuck. The system is a fresh Windows installation. I have also compared the codecs installed on the non-Working Windows 11 installation and installed the only difference / missing one compared to a working Windows 10 installation, to no avail.

It turns out that the affected PCs were using integrated intel graphics chips. Updating the graphics device driver to the newest version solved the problem.
The old graphics driver wasn't really that old, and the problem did not exist before Windows 11, and I still don't understand why Windows Media Player could play the affected videos, but I still want to post this "solution" for the benefit of other who might run into this problem.
